# What is a creative synonym for "flexible"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, vocabulary

I'm trying to find new ways to describe a technology that can work in many different contexts without using the words "flexible," "agile," or "resilient." I've found that most synonyms easily found on online dictionaries don't quite fit or sound like jargon. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/flexible

Comment: widely applicable

Answer (score 1):

"versatile" seems like what you're looking for.

from [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/versatile), adjective, definition 2

> - "A tool, machine, or material that is versatile can be used for many different purposes.
>     e.g. Never before has computing been so versatile."

Comment: +1 Seems right on target.